# Write a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines pos, neg, total, average

Tags: java, netbeans

(Count positive and negative numbers and compute the average of numbers) Write
a program that reads an unspecified number of integers, determines how many
positive and negative values have been read, and computes the total and average of
the input values (not counting zeros). Your program ends with the input 0. Display
the average as a floating-point number. Here is a sample run:

Enter an integer, the input ends if it is 0: 1 2 -1 3 0

The number of positives is 3

The number of negatives is 1

The total is 5.0

The average is 1.25

**I have 2 major issues. 1) I cannot get the loop to stop. 2) even if I did, the average comes up short. Using the example above, my average is always 1.0, not 1.25 as it should be. It's like the program is reading 5 numbers total instead of the 4 numbers that equate to 5.** What is seen in the code below is all I can use: Bare basics of java...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     int positive = 0, negative = 0, total = 0, count = 0;

     float average;

     System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
     int number = input.nextInt();

     while(number != 0) {
        total += number;
        count++;

        if(number > 0){
        positive++;
        }

        else if(number < 0){
        negative++;
        }

     average = total / count;

     System.out.println("The number of positives is "+ positive);
     System.out.println("The number of negatives is "+ negative);
     System.out.println("The total is "+ total);
     System.out.println("The average is "+ average);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: just before end of loop you need `number = input.nextInt();` to read next number

Comment: --Placing the "System" print outs outside of the while statement allows for me input numbers BUT it does nothing else after that! I'm confused!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read more numbers. You read one value before your loop. You could do something like

```
int number;
while((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
    total += number;
    count++;
    if(number > 0){
        positive++;
    } else if(number < 0) {
        negative++;
    }
} // <-- end loop body.
float average = total / (float) count; // <-- not integer math.
System.out.println("The number of positives is " + positive);
System.out.println("The number of negatives is " + negative);
System.out.println("The total is " + total);
System.out.println("The average is " + average);
```

Comment: Ty for your help. I don't know why everyone keeps marking my posts down as if I'm supposed already know everything. I don't understand most of this stuff half of the time, and restless re-reading does nothing for me... `while((number = input.nextInt()) != 0) {`  The chapter I'm in never covered this statement being used in such a way... I'm limited to what information is given to me and I wouldn't have known to use the statement that way if I was looking for it... I don't understand what research area I'm supposed to look at to know how to use it--technique.

Comment: If `average` has been assigned as a float, why would I need for `count` to be a float as well?

Comment: @ChrisRedfieldea The assignment and testing the side effect is a very common idiom in Java. The result of dividing two `int` values is an `int`, widening it to a `float` doesn't grant the result extra precision; instead, promote one of the values to a `float` and then the result is a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the do while.

```
import java.util.*;  
public class PosAndNeg   {   
public static void main(String [] args){  
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  

int positive = 0, negative = 0, total = 0, count = 0;  
int number;
float average;

     System.out.println("Enter the number: ");
     do { number = input.nextInt();
     total += number;
        count++;  
           if(number > 0){
           positive++;
        }
             else if(number < 0){
            negative++;
        }
    }
     while(number != 0);

     average = total / count;

     System.out.println("The number of positives is "+ positive);
     System.out.println("The number of negatives is "+ negative);
     System.out.println("The total is "+ total);
     System.out.println("The average is "+ average);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
// use type conversion while evaluating average
import java.util.Scanner;
public class newClass{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int pos=0;
    int neg=0;
    int total=0;
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the total numbers user want to enter");

int  i=sc.nextInt();
int [] num= new int[i];
System.out.println("Please enter number");
for (int j = 0; j < num.length; j++)
{   

    num[j] = sc.nextInt();
    if(num[j]>0)
        pos++;
    else
        neg++;
    total=total+num[j];

}
System.out.println(num.length);
double avg =(float)total/(num.length);
System.out.println("positive count="+pos+"negative count="+neg+" average ="+avg);
}
}
```

Comment: please also  provide description and  explanation what you answered

Comment: it is quite simple problem                                                                        1.here i have declare three variables "pos" to count positive integer,"neg" to count negative integers and "total" for storing total sum of all integer.

Answer (score -3):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewClass{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N=0,p=0,t=0;
 System.out.println("enter 
integers");
Scanner obj=new Scanner 
(System.in);
    int a=obj.nextInt();
    while (a!=0){
    t+=a;
    if (a<0){
    N++;
    }
    else if (a>0){
    p++;
    }
    int b=obj.nextInt();
    a=b;
    }
    System.out.println("the 
    number of negative 
    numbers is\t\t"+N);
    System.out.println("the 
    number of positive number 
    is\t\t"+p);
    float l=N+p;
    float average=(float) t/l;
    System.out.println("the total 
    is\t\t"+t);
    System.out.println("the 
    average is\t\t"+average);
  }
}
```